# codeigniter одновременный запрос к двум разным БД или синхронизация таблиц в разных БД

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, синхронизация

На работе по наследству досталось 6 приложений на php + Codeigniter + БД mySql. 
Каждая БД содержит в себе таблицы (справочники), которые повторяются в этих БД в разных сочетаниях. Например таблицы стандартов, товаров, пользователи и т.д. Периодически есть потребность обновлять данные в этих справочниках и этот процесс очень утомительный, найти где эти таблицы повторяются и обновить. Сейчас пишу еще одну программу и также нужно будет там использовать некоторые таблицы (справочники).

В начале думал создать БД как единую БД для таких таблиц (справочниуов). Тогда можно было бы делать один раз обновление и из других приложений обращаться к этой БД, Но так и не нашел как в codeigniter сделать одновременный запрос к двум разным БД (объединить таблицы из разных БД). 
Никак не могу придумать как еще организовать обновление таких таблиц в разных БД. Может у кого есть опыт в реализации подобного, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно в MySQL при обращении к таблице из другой базы просто используется префикс - имя этой БД

```
SELECT tbl.name FROM other_db.my_table tbl WHERE tbl.id = 100
```

Comment: @EugeneOleynikov И там не используются имена таблиц? Запрос выполняет не Codeigniter, a MySQL. Codeigniter запрос только фомирует

Comment: @EugeneOleynikov Вы **пробовали** указать имя таблицы с указанием имени базы или Вы только теоретизируете?

Comment: Да, действительно работает. Хотя был уверен что не работает. Вроде даже пробовал раньше.

Comment: @EugeneOleynikov Если мой ответ верен, то отметьте его как правильный